# ffmpeg mute specific time

Tags: ffmpeg

Looking to edit a blip out of the beginning of a video/audio file...

Anyone know why this doesn't work as expected?

`ffmpeg -i ~/Downloads/in.mov -vcodec copy -af volume=enable='between(t,0,3)':volume=0 ~/Downloads/out2.mov`

```
[Parsed_volume_0 @ 0x7fa8a8d01680] [Eval @ 0x7fff5544ebe0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'
[Parsed_volume_0 @ 0x7fa8a8d01680] Error when evaluating the volume expression 'between(t'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fa8a8d01440] Error initializing filter 'volume' with args 'between(t'
Error opening filters!
```